# Listing lat/long coordinates of every point inside polygon or shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, buffer

This is likely a beginner question but I've seen numerous posts on how to export the boundaries of a polygon as coordinates, but none on exporting the area of a polygon as coordinates. I am ultimately trying to create a set of lat/long coordinates, rounded to 3 digits, which represent every coordinate within a given distance (say 500 meters) of the coast in a given state. Starting with a shapefile outlining the shoreline, I created a 500 meter buffer so I now have a new shapefile encompassing the area within 500 meters of the shoreline.

[image]

[image]

The buffer is made up of a whole bunch of different polygons meshed together (see snippet of attribute table shown), but I'm not sure that matters for the overall question.

Is there a way to export the buffer shapefile as a list of every lat/long coordinate within 500 meters of the coast or is there a better way to think about this problem?

I am using QGIS.

Comment: There are an infinite number of points inside a polygon, so your question lacks clarity. You should certainly dissolve the polygons, then intersect with the land polygons to get *land* within 500m of the coast.

Comment: @Vince thank you! Those both sound like reasonable next steps before attempting to list the coordinates. I understand technically there are an infinite number of coordinate points inside a polygon, and clarified the question that I'm looking for rounded lat/long coordinates.

Comment: [Generate regular points](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#regular-points) with your required spacing, intersect or select by location with your buffers, export point coordinates.

Comment: If you also wish to ask about ArcMap then please do that in a separate question so that you can describe precisely what you've tried and where you're stuck using that software.